# Office365 - Get list of all Planner Plans

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I would like to retrieve a list of all Planner Plans and number of tasks in each Plan. Goal is to understand which plans are actually in use. I used the Graph API for this. However it appears that most the Graph endpoints for Planner and Tasks use *Delegation Permissions*. In other words, I have to be part of each Planner Plan to even query for it. So even as **Global Admin** I am unable to pull this information. Is there any way to query for

1. List of ALL Planner Plans in the tenant
2. Owner for each Planner Plan
3. Number of tasks in each Plan

Thanks in advance,
Jake

Answer (score 1):

You can now use application permissions to read this data.

Outdated reply:

> Unfortunately it is not possible to get this through Microsoft Graph
> API right now. However we do have another API, which is meant for
> admins to be able to export their tenant's data, and it can be used to
> get this information. You should contact support for this process.

Comment: it will be helpful if you can share any Microsoft Docs link which describes this API. Also we can refer this docs link when we contact support. Thanks.

Comment: I also have this requirement.

Comment: @morleyc create support in azure portal:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Comment: @morleyc m365 create support, go to m365 admin center with admin account, and left panel->support blade-> new service request. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf01y.png And [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/business-video/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide) introduce more details.

Comment: Kind of a useless answer without a link to the document.